# Why props are not setting as state?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to set state of a child via props but its not setting up, Also I have a doubt why BarChart component render so many times here.

Which is a good practice 'to get all store value in parent component and pass it via props or I should read store value in child component and set it as local state'?

P.S: redux store

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import Chartjs from "chart.js";

const chartConfig = {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Green", "Yellow", "Blue"],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: ["# of Values"],
        data: [2, 10, 9, 25],
      },
    ],
  },
};

const BarChart = (props) => {
  const chartContainer = useRef(null);
  const [chartInstance, setChartInstance] = useState(null);
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState(null)
  console.log(props.values) //This value coming from server in parent component, this value is correct and logging correct value
 
 useEffect(() => {
    if (chartContainer && chartContainer.current) {
      const newChartInstance = new Chartjs(chartContainer.current, chartConfig);
      setChartInstance(newChartInstance);
    }
  }, [chartContainer]);

  useEffect(() => {

    setChartData(props.values)
    console.log("Yes!, I am In")
  }, [])
  
console.log(chartData) //null[enter image description here][1]
  const updateDataset = (datasetIndex, newData) => {
    chartInstance.data.datasets[datasetIndex].data = newData;
    chartInstance.update();
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ padding: "20px" }}>
      <canvas ref={chartContainer} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default BarChart;
```

This is console screenshot in this line number 49 is props.values and 62 is chartData
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/71BI2.png

Comment: Why do you even need `chartData` in a local state if it comes from the parent via props anyways?

Comment: add some code related to rendeting BarChart in parent component and passed data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you passing the values of chartData through props, then the chartData initialization should happen using those props.

For example:
`const [chartData, setChartData] = useState(props.values)`;

Additionally, your updateDataset function should also be called before setting up the chartInstance, because the values for the bar-chart are passed to the BarChart Component before the component renders. Hence to override the chartConfig dataset values, its important to update the initial chart config.

An update to your chartInstance effect would look something like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (chartContainer && chartContainer.current) {
      // added the following line for updating the initial chartConfig
      updateDataset(0, chartData)

      const newChartInstance = new Chartjs(chartContainer.current, chartConfig);
      setChartInstance(newChartInstance);
    }
  }, [chartContainer]);
```

I would suggest something like:

```
 const updateDataset = (datasetIndex, newData) => {
    if(chartInstance){
      chartInstance.data.datasets[datasetIndex].data = newData;
      chartInstance.update();
    } else {
      chartConfig.data.datasets[datasetIndex].data = newData;
    }
    
  };
```

You can refer to the whole solution at the following stackblitz page:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bmc5jq